# Django form - set label

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-forms

I have  a form that inherits from 2 other forms. In my form, I want to change the label of a field that was defined in one of the parent forms. Does anyone know how this can be done?

I'm trying to do it in my `__init__`, but it throws an error saying that "'RegistrationFormTOS' object has no attribute 'email'". Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks.

Here is my form code:

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from registration.forms import RegistrationFormUniqueEmail
from registration.forms import RegistrationFormTermsOfService

attrs_dict = { 'class': 'required' }

class RegistrationFormTOS(RegistrationFormUniqueEmail, RegistrationFormTermsOfService):
    """
    Subclass of ``RegistrationForm`` which adds a required checkbox
    for agreeing to a site's Terms of Service.

    """
    email2 = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(attrs_dict, maxlength=75)), label=_(u'verify email address'))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.email.label = "New Email Label"
        super(RegistrationFormTOS, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_email2(self):
        """
        Verifiy that the values entered into the two email fields
        match. 
        """
        if 'email' in self.cleaned_data and 'email2' in self.cleaned_data:
            if self.cleaned_data['email'] != self.cleaned_data['email2']:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_(u'You must type the same email each time'))
        return self.cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You should use:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(RegistrationFormTOS, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['email'].label = "New Email Label"
```

Note first you should use the super call.

Comment: not work for PasswordChagneForm :-(

Comment: This works, but you shouldn't use a constructer if the label doesn't need to be customized per-instance.  @zx1986 see my answer below wrt. PasswordChangeForm.

Answer (score 69):

Here's an example taken from [Overriding the default fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields):

> ```
> from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
>
> class AuthorForm(ModelForm):
>     class Meta:
>         model = Author
>         fields = ('name', 'title', 'birth_date')
>         labels = {
>             'name': _('Writer'),
>         }
>         help_texts = {
>             'name': _('Some useful help text.'),
>         }
>         error_messages = {
>             'name': {
>                 'max_length': _("This writer's name is too long."),
>             },
>         }
> ```

Comment: how to use it in django template

Comment: not work for form inheritance from PasswordChangeFrom

Comment: When using `forms.py` this is a great approach for renaming labels (which can be incredibly helpful when labels need to be dynamically built rather than static). Worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 23):

You can set `label` as an attribute of field when you define form.

```
class GiftCardForm(forms.ModelForm):
    card_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label="Cardholder Name")
    card_number = forms.CharField(max_length=50, label="Card Number")
    card_code = forms.CharField(max_length=20, label="Security Code")
    card_expirate_time = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label="Expiration (MM/YYYY)")

    class Meta:
        model = models.GiftCard
        exclude = ('price', )
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it doesn't explain how to change `the label of a field that was defined in one of the parent forms` - the parent form is the important bit.

Comment: It didn't work for me... `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'label'`

Answer (score 9):

You access fields in a form via the 'fields' dict:

```
self.fields['email'].label = "New Email Label"
```

That's so that you don't have to worry about form fields having name clashes with the form class methods.  (Otherwise you couldn't have a field named 'clean' or 'is_valid')  Defining the fields directly in the class body is mostly just a convenience.

Answer (score 3):

Try on Models.py

```
email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="E-Mail Address")
email_confirmation = models.EmailField(verbose_name="Please repeat")
```

Answer (score 2):

It don't work for model inheritance, but you can set the label directly in the model

```
email = models.EmailField("E-Mail Address")
email_confirmation = models.EmailField("Please repeat")
```

Answer (score 1):

While using a class' constructor to change the field label for an instance works, it's better from an object-oriented design standpoint to make the change at the class level if the label doesn't need to be customized per-instance.

For example, the following will change the label on **PasswordChangeForm**'s **new_password2** field from "*New password confirmation*" to "*Confirm Password*":

```
class MyPasswordChangeForm(PasswordChangeForm):
  PasswordChangeForm.base_fields['new_password2'].label = 'Confirm Password'
```

Take a look in **django/forms/forms.py**, you'll see that **DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass** removes the fields from a class' attribute list and places them in **base_fields** and **declared_fields**.

```
class Form(BaseForm, metaclass=DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass):
...

class DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass(MediaDefiningClass):
    """Collect Fields declared on the base classes."""
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs):
        # Collect fields from current class and remove them from attrs.
        attrs['declared_fields'] = {
            key: attrs.pop(key) for key, value in list(attrs.items())
            if isinstance(value, Field)
        }

        new_class = super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)

        # Walk through the MRO.
        declared_fields = {}
        for base in reversed(new_class.__mro__):
            # Collect fields from base class.
            if hasattr(base, 'declared_fields'):
                declared_fields.update(base.declared_fields)

            # Field shadowing.
            for attr, value in base.__dict__.items():
                if value is None and attr in declared_fields:
                    declared_fields.pop(attr)

        new_class.base_fields = declared_fields
        new_class.declared_fields = declared_fields
```

There's a comment in **BaseForm** that provides further explanation:

```
class BaseForm:
...
    # The base_fields class attribute is the *class-wide* definition of
    # fields. Because a particular *instance* of the class might want to
    # alter self.fields, we create self.fields here by copying base_fields.
    # Instances should always modify self.fields; they should not modify
    # self.base_fields.
```

Answer (score 0):

if all other solutions don't work, this one worked for me (to change the user class label to django contrib auth)

```
#in models.py

User._meta.get_field('username').verbose_name = "new name"
```