# How to declare a form field in Django, if it has the same name as a Python keyword?

Tags: python, django

I've got a simple form in Django, that looks something like this:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField()
    from = forms.DateField()
    until = forms.DateField()
```

Which fails with a SyntaxError, because `from` is a Python keyword.

I rather not change the name of the field; It fits better than any of the alternatives, and I'm fussy about how it appears to the end user.  (The form is using 'GET', so the field name is visible in the URL.)

I realize I could just use something, like `from_` instead, but I was initially thought there might be some way to explicitly provide the field name, for cases like this.  (eg. By supplying a `name='whatever'` parameter in the Field constructor.)  It turn's out [there isn't](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py#L43).

At the moment I'm using [dynamic form generation](http://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/) to get around the issue, which isn't too bad, but it's still a bit of a hack...

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField()
    from_ = forms.DateField()
    until = forms.DateField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['from'] = self.fields['from_']
        del self.fields['from_']
```

Is there any more elegant way of having a form field named `from`, or any other Python keyword?

Comment: Capitalize the word? I'm pretty sure the keywords are only lower-case.

Comment: something similar is to set the label in the __init__ ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636905/django-form-set-label

Comment: The label is the textual description, not the query parameter that gets used, so that doesn't do the trick.

Comment: so the question assumes that you use form action=GET?

Comment: i think adding an extra field parameter with the http form field name would be a good new feature for the form field class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't name things after keywords, even if you find a work around, it will probably end up biting you later.

Use a synonym or add a prefix/suffix instead.

E.g.
`start` -> `finish`
`begin` -> `end`
`date_from` -> `date_to`

Comment: I'd agree if it wasn't case that it makes an end-user-visible difference.  I'd rather not make decisions on what my URLs will look like to the end-user based on the semantics of the language that I happen to be using for the backend code.