# Mapping a different field OneToOneField in a ModelForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have two django models related with a OneToOneField. I'll show the relevant fields:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, db_index=True)
```

And

```
class PasswordRecovery(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    token = models.CharField(default=utils.make_token)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

Then I have a form for the PasswordRecovery model

```
class PasswordRecoveryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password_check = forms.CharField(max_length=128)
    class Meta:
        model = PasswordRecovery
        fields = ('user', 'password', 'password_check')
```

A few details are omitted here. Tell me if you think they are relevant.

The problem is that the user field shows as a 'select' element and I would like it to be an email field. Instead of being able to chose a user from a lista I want it instead to required the email to be typed.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override the clean_user method to pass the User objects

```
class PasswordRecoveryForm(forms.ModelForm):

    user = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    password_check = forms.CharField(max_length=128)

    class Meta:
        model = PasswordRecovery
        fields = ('user', 'password', 'password_check')

    def clean_user(self):
        user_email = self.cleaned_data['user']
        if User.objects.get(email__iexact=user_email):
            return User.objects.get(email__iexact=user_email)
        return None

    #If you wanna to fill in the email add this
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PasswordRecoveryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            self.fields['user'].initial = self.instance.user.email
```

Comment: This did it for me. There's only one problem: the field on the form is rendered with name="user", therefore Chrome does not use autocomplete for emails. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Hmm.. Actually there's another problem. I want the form to update existing entries, but I can't get an instance without validating the form (I need the email address).

Comment: For generated html field name you can find the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801910/override-django-form-fields-name-attr)

Comment: For edit mode, loading email from passed user instance, add the `__init__` method