# Django insert multiply input values from one form

Tags: jquery, python, django, forms, django-forms

the question is how to insert multiply values from one form in Django form submit. The form has only one input, where requeires different numbers. I know for model set form's and inline formsets, but this is different problem. The form is set into HTML page as only one form field. And with some jQuery I create about 10 other input values with same form name. Better explanation I will provide with code.

## models.py

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    organization = models.ForeignKey('Organization')
    prod_serv    = models.ForeignKey('Product_service')
    out_invoice  = models.ForeignKey('OutgoingInvoice')
```

Simple model in django models.

## forms.py

```
class ModelForTest(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
        exclude = ('organization','out_invoice', 'prod_serv', )
```

## views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form5 = ModelForTest(request.POST, prefix='form5')
    if form5.is_valid():
        u = form5.save(commit=False)
        for code in form5.cleaned_data['code']:
            u.organization_id = org_id.id  
            u.out_invoice_id= b.id
            test = Product_service.objects.get(product_code=code)
            u.prod_serv_id = test.id
            u.save()
    else:
        form5 = ModelForTest(prefix='form5')

return render_to_response(template, dict(form5=form5), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here is problem in `for` loop, where I must extract all values from fields named by `code`. I just get first input value from HTML, other values won't loop inside `for loop`. How can this be done, I mean how to extratc all values from HTML and insert into model after form submit.

Comment: I don't understand this at all. What are you doing? Why? Why not have proper form fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change all entries in your template `name=code` to `name=code[]`

to accomplish this using Django Forms – look at @Daniel Roseman answer here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8802119/3033586

```
FIELD_NAME_MAPPING = {
    'code': 'code[]'
}
```