# Django model forms - order of dynamically created fields

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

**How can I set order fields in Django ModelForm, when I dont know the number and the exact name of the fields?**

I have a model named FormEntry, for which I want to create a ModelForm.
The only displaced Field should be plugin_data and dynamically created custom derivatives of it (label, initial,..) with language prefix (based on languages settings).
So if I have set in the settings the languages cs and en, then those fields must be available:

```
plugin_data, label_cs,label_en,initial_cs,initial_en,...
```

The new fields are dynamically created in `__init__`, and I don't know how can I use new feature (Form.field_order) in [Django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.order_fields) when I don't know the names of the fields in advance.

Comment: What is it you want to achieve here ? [Override the form's fields names ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801910/override-django-form-fields-name-attr) Because if you are talking about dynamically generating *database* fields on the flight based on the settings, I have a pretty bad feeling about it. Especially when it comes to a client setting like language.

Comment: No, I want to simply change the order of fields of the form. Now they are at the result form randomly, and i want to sort them, ideally in alphabetical order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, solved it myself:

```
class someForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FormElementEntryTransForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # creating new fields
        #...
        self.order_fields(sorted(self.fields.keys())) # sort fields alphabetically
```