# Django - Forms - change field names on template

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have to following `forms.py` and `models.py`:

```
# models
class BHA_Component(models.Model):
    item_description = models.CharField(max_length=111)
    num_of_jts = models.CharField(max_length=111)
    length = models.CharField(max_length=111)
    cum_length = models.CharField(max_length=111)
    outer_d = models.CharField(max_length=111)

# forms
class BHA_Component_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = BHA_Component
        fields = '__all__'
```

So far, I've been printing the field names on the screen using html like this:

```
{% for field in bha_form %}
    <label>{{ field.name }}</label>
{% endfor %}
```

I passed in the form, `bha_form` as a context variable in `views.py`.

If I use this set of code, it this on a screen:

`item_description, num_of_jts, length, cum_length, outer_d`

But I want to print this on a screen:

`Item Description, # of jts, Lenth, Cum. Len., OD`

As you can see, I can't get this output by simply using some `s.upper()` method, or regex method, because there no certain string transformation relationship between the original field names and the output I want.

I want to manually decide what field names will be printed on a screen for each field. But I don't want to do this by hard coding html elements like this:

```
<label>Item Description</label>
<label># of jts</label>
<label>Length</label>
```

I want to do this on the backend using Django. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set a name on your fields. See [verbose field names](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#verbose-field-names) in the documentation.

```
class BHA_Component(models.Model):
    item_description = models.CharField('Item Description', max_length=111)
```

The verbose name will automatically be picked up (and capitalized) by the [form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/) to create label text.

I cannot check right now, but if my memory is correct, I believe you should be using `field.label` rather than `field.name` in your label though.