# Django Form Field name Changing- Class Based View

Tags: python, django

In order to change the name in the form label in Django class-based view, I have to write this code into **get_context_data**

```
 ctx['form'].fields['dob'].label = 'Date of Birth'
```

This changes dob to Date of Birth in form. Suppose there are 10 fields like this in the model. Is there a better way to change the name of all the form fields instead of writing 10 line of code?

Comment: Better to do in the forms init method. https://stackoverflow.com/a/637020/2282638

Comment: define a `dict` with field label and label you want to assign, the iterate -  all in `init` method.this would be cleanest way i assume

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not via the method you are attempting.

If this is a `ModelForm`, consider passing `verbose_name` in the corresponding model's field definitions so the labels are used automatically on the form:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    dob = models.DateField(verbose_name='date of birth')
```

This is neater and more maintainable generally.

If your goal is to cut down on code, this will still accomplish what you want, as you're simply adding a parameter to each of the model field definitions instead of adding several 'new lines' to your codebase.