# I want to change the labels of the login form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

I want to change the labels of the login form, but this does not happen. When running, these labels show their default state, "login" and "password".
thanks for your guide

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile


class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='نام کاربری')
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, label='پسورد')
```

Custom change of labels

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/637020

Comment: how do you generate your login form?

Comment: there is also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28162469
Have you tried any of them?

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code. You misspelt `label` as `lable`,
update your code like the below:

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
    self.fields['username'].label = "نام کاربری"
    self.fields['password'].label = "پسورد"
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem was not solved, you can see the original code in this link

Comment: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Django-4-by-example/blob/main/Chapter04/bookmarks/account/forms.py

Comment: I review the code the thing is this must work. The simple way is to provide a label like this `username = forms.CharField(label='your label here')` and the other way is what I shared with you above.